# Error while installing RTextTools 1.4.2 (Windows)

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to install `RTextTools` 1.4.2 in Windows,
and I get the following error :

```
trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/lava_1.4.0.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/lava_1.4.0.zip'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘lava’ failed
```

Because of the missing `lava` package, I'm unable to load `RTextTools`
package. I tried different CRAN mirrors, but same error.

Is there a fix/update available, so that I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the lava package directly from CRAN rather than getting it from the IIT mirror. 
This is the link : http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/lava/index.html

download the r-release: lava_1.4.1.zip and extract the zip into the packages folder in your R installation. 
Hope this helps